# Twice disconnect: How would you deal with this situation

Tags: c++

I have code which checks if smart card is inserted or removed:

```
void checkCard(void *p)
{
//...
while(true)
{
    if (ReaderState1.dwEventState & SCARD_STATE_EMPTY)
    {
     // Smart card removed, call disconnect
     disconnectCard(cardHandle);

    }
    else
    {
     // Smart card inserted do smth else
    }


}

}
```

In `main` I call above thread:

```
int main()
{
...
    if(establichContext(_hSC) == true)
        {

            // Start thread 
            _beginthread(checkCard, 0, NULL);

            // Sleep
            Sleep(1000000); // or some other logic which halts program for some time

            // Disconnect from card and release context
            disconnectCard(cardHandle);
            releaseContext(_hSC);

        }
}
```

My problem is if smart card was already removed - by the first code snippet (`checkCard` function), calling `disconnectCard` - second time as in `main`, fails. How would you deal with such situation?

`disconnectCard` - just uses SCardDisconnect method inside )http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379475(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have a flag that you check and set in the `disconnectCard` function.

Like

```
void disconnectCard(someType someArgument)
{
    static bool disconnected = false;

    if (disconnected)
        return;  // Already disconnected

    // ... Do stuff ...

    disconnected = true;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like good idea? Or I will set it inside this statement `if (ReaderState1.dwEventState & SCARD_STATE_EMPTY)`?

Comment: I implemented similar logic in the `checkCard` function, thanks. Then I check in main if it is already removed or not ..

Comment: This is a race condition. The OP specified the threading context in code.

Comment: @sehe: can you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: `disconnected` should be either atomic or guarded by a mutex. Otherwise it's perfectly reasonable that a thread read 'disconnected' as false, while it is already being disconnected on the other thread and consequently both threads proceed executing the disconnect code. _Simultaneously_.

Comment: @sehe: I think I see what you mean, you say if simultaneously: card is removed and also main program finishes (e.g., Sleep time outs). right? This is unlikely in my app I think, as the program will probably be set such that it runs "always" but I will keep in mind what you said

Answer (score 0):

I would handle the disconnection from the checkCard thread only.  You can do this by using a flag to control the while loop in your worker thread, then clear this flag from main to stop the thread when you want to stop checking the card.  You can then disconnect the card as part of shutting the thread down.

For example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>

void checkCard(void *p)
{
    bool &keepgoing = *((bool *) p);
    while (keepgoing)
    {
        // do what you want with check card
        std::cout << "checking card" << std::endl;
        Sleep(2000);
    }
    // if card still connected disconnect
    std::cout << "cleanly exited" << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    bool run = true;
    _beginthread(checkCard, 0, &run);

    Sleep(15000);

    // clear this flag to tell the worker thread to stop
    run = false;
    // wait for worker thread to finish - could have worker set flag
    // again so you can test it has finished card disconnect etc.
    Sleep(2000);
    // done.
    std::cout << "finished" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is that the behaviour you're looking for?